# Try to upload Excel or csv file but PHPexcel not working PHP 8.0.13 version

Tags: phpexcel

When try to upload Excel or CSV file file not uplaod, PHPexcel not working PHP 8.0.13 version but this PHPexcel library is working PHP 7.4.26 version(file uploaded successfully here). Please help how to solve this problem.

Comment: shared some of your code please guy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
                    include(__DIR__ .'/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

Comment: // load uploaded file
      $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
      $objReader->setDelimiter(';');
      
      $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);

Comment: Error showing for following line-                                                                    include(__DIR__ .'/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');                This error only show PHP 8.0.13 version